# lit element typescript reflect:true

Tags: typescript, lit-element

So I am trying to use `Typescript` with `lit-element`

However i am unsure how to set options such as `reflect`

in plain Javascript you would write:

```
  static get properties() { return {
    test: { reflect: true }
  };}
```

But in typescript you declare properties like this:

```
@property()
test : string;
```

But how do i add the `reflect:true`?

if i do like this:

```
@property()
test : {reflect: true};
```

it doesn't work because it thinks that is the variable type.

So how can add these options?

Comment: The JavaScript way is the right way. It's perfectly valid and strictly typed TypeScript.

Comment: @AluanHaddad how can i set the data type with that setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [property](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/api/modules/_lit_element_.html#property) decorator accepts a [PropertyDeclaration](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/api/interfaces/_lit_element_.propertydeclaration.html) argument. So you can pass reflect to the decorator.

```js
@property({ reflect: true })
test : string;
```